# Is it possible to change the timestep of SUMO output?

Tags: sumo

I am using SUMO to generate a network from openstreetmaps. I am interested on observing my results of vehicle positions in smaller timestep than 1 second, but for example 0.5 second. Is it possible to do this change?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Simply call sumo with the step-length option set to your desired value:
sumo --step-length 0.5 in your case. See the [docs](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/SUMO) for more options